# DC Bar Chart x-Axis Sort Alphabetically

Tags: sorting, d3.js, dc.js

i have an use case where i need to sort bar chart alphabetically, i have sorted some of bar chart using .ordering method, but it is not working from key sort.
this

```
bar
  .margins({top: 20, left: 30, right: 10, bottom: config.xaxisorientation ? 60 : 20})
  .width(barWidth).height(barHeight)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .brushOn(false)
  .xAxisLabel(config.xaxislabel ? config.xaxislabel : '')
  .yAxisLabel(config.yaxislabel ? config.yaxislabel : '')
  .dimension(dim)
  .renderLabel(true)
  .renderType("group")
  .title(titleAggre)
  .elasticY(true)
  .group(grp)
  .valueAccessor(grpAggre);

bar.yAxis().ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

bar.ordering(function(a) {
  return a.key.toLowerCase();
});
```

[image]

Data looks like this ;

```
[{
    "c1": "profile",
    "c2": "admin",
    "c3": "e2e_mf",
    "count:1
  }, {
    "c1": "profile",
    "c2": "admin",
    "c3": "aporec"
    "count":2
  }, {
    "c1": "profile",
    "c2": "admin",
    "c3": "aporec",
    "count":10
  }]
```

Comment: What does your data look like ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy, C3 is dimesnion and measure is group value  [{
  "c1": "profile",
  "c2": "admin",
  "c3": "e2e_mf", "measure":1
 }, {
  "c1": "profile",
  "c2": "admin",
  "c3": "aporec"
 }, {
  "c1": "profile",
  "c2": "admin",
  "c3": "aporec", "measure":1
 }]

Comment: ok so what is the count on the left hand side ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy, sum of measure

Answer (score 0):

This looks like this bug:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/772

which was fixed in dc.js 2.0 beta 6. Is it possible you are using an earlier version?

I am not sure if the bug is present in the 1.7.* version or not.